# Costmap navigation 2 not working

Tags: costmap-2d, nav2d, global-costmap, local-costmap, nav2

I'm using robot pepper from Softbank Robotics, Rtabmap and navigation 2 with ROS2 foxy. I'm having problems in nav2 costmaps.
When I visualize the costmaps in Rviz2 it works fine for about 1 sec then I obtain this:
[image]

Then this:
[image]

This is my configuration file:

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_link"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "beam"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::OmniMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: laser

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugin: "goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      stateful: True
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      global_frame: map
      robot_radius: 0.25 # Pepper has an actual radius of 0.35
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      resolution: 0.02
      plugins: [ "static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer" ]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: pointcloud # scan
        footprint_clearing_enabled: True
        #max_obstacle_height: 0.8
        #min_obstacle_height: -2.0
        pointcloud:
          topic: /camera/depth/points
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
          marking: True
          clearing: True
          obstacle_max_range: 7.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.2
          raytrace_max_range: 5.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.1
        #scan:
        #  topic: /laser
        #  obstacle_range: 5.0  # Detect obstacles at this range
        #  raytrace_range: 8.0  # Pepper limit of pointcloud
        #  clearing: True
        #  marking: True
        #  data_type: "LaserScan"
        #  inf_is_valid: False
        static_layer:
          plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
          map_subscribe_transient_local: True
          enabled: true
          subscribe_to_updates: true
          transform_tolerance: 10.0
        inflation_layer:
          plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
          enabled: true
          inflation_radius: 0.3  # Can be tweaked
          cost_scaling_factor: 5.0
          inflate_unknown: false
          inflate_around_unknown: true
        always_send_full_costmap: True

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      rolling_window: true
      width: 4
      height: 4
      resolution: 0.02
      robot_radius: 0.25 # Pepper has an actual radius of 0.35
      plugins: ["inflation_layer", "obstacle_layer" ]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        enabled: True
        cost_scaling_factor: 5.0
        inflation_radius: 0.3
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: pointcloud #scan
        footprint_clearing_enabled: True
        #max_obstacle_height: 1.5
        #min_obstacle_height: -2.0
        pointcloud:
          topic: /camera/depth/points
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
          marking: True
          clearing: True
          obstacle_max_range: 7.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.5
          raytrace_max_range: 5.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.1
        #scan:
        #  topic: /laser
        #  max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        #  clearing: True
        #  marking: True
        #  raytrace_range: 8.0
        #  obstacle_range: 7.5
        #  data_type: "LaserScan"
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    #yaml_filename: "turtlebot3_world.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5000
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: False

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "back_up", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    back_up:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: False
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
```

Have you an hint on how resolve this behaviour
Thanks in advance